# Drop rows that contains the data between specific dates

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

The file contains data by date and time:
All I want I want drop rows that contains between these dates and includes the start and end dates:

```
data_file =pd.read_csv(r"MyFile.csv", header = None)

start_date = '01/08/2017'
end_date = '29/8/2017'

my_dataframe = my_dataframe.drop([start_date : end_date])
data_file = data_file.to_csv('summary.csv', index = False, header = False)
```

Any Idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sample:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2017-07-02', periods=10, freq='10D')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': rng, 'a': range(10)})  
print (df)
        Date  a
0 2017-07-02  0
1 2017-07-12  1
2 2017-07-22  2
3 2017-08-01  3
4 2017-08-11  4
5 2017-08-21  5
6 2017-08-31  6
7 2017-09-10  7
8 2017-09-20  8
9 2017-09-30  9
```

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) for filter by condition with chain by `|` for bitwise OR:

```
start_date = '2017-08-01'
end_date = '2017-08-29'

df1 = df[(df['Date'] < start_date) | (df['Date']  > end_date)]
print (df1)
        Date  a
0 2017-07-02  0
1 2017-07-12  1
2 2017-07-22  2
6 2017-08-31  6
7 2017-09-10  7
8 2017-09-20  8
9 2017-09-30  9
```

Or filter by [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) and invert mask by `~`:

```
df1 = df[~df['Date'].between(start_date ,end_date)]
print (df1)
        Date  a
0 2017-07-02  0
1 2017-07-12  1
2 2017-07-22  2
6 2017-08-31  6
7 2017-09-10  7
8 2017-09-20  8
9 2017-09-30  9
```